# Getting Dom elements from "request" in nodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, dom, request

Hi I am wondering if there is a way to make a request using the "request" package, then with the response.body being a html document, get the node elements from it. say:

```
let data = response.body//html document
let buttonArray = []
let loadedButtons = data.queryElements("button")
for(let button in loadedButtons){
    buttonArray.push(button.innerHTML)
}
```

Cheers,
Mitchell

Comment: You have to parse the HTML into a pseudo DOM that you can then query.  There are multiple packages that can do that.

Comment: Thanks for that, was hoping node had a built in HTML parser that could do it, but i will look for a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) package to load the DOM and get a jQuery-like API to query data.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
let buttonArray = [];
let loadedButtons = $("button").each((i, e) => {
    buttonArray.push($(e).html());
});
```